# Copilot stopped working on vscode after trying multiple fixes

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

Randomly my copilot has stopped working (I still have time left on my free trial). The problem seems to be that no matter what I do I cannot get the pop up to authorise copilot to appear when installing the extension again. Does anyone have any idea why?

I've tried everything from:

- Signing out of Github on vscode and signing back in.
- Uninstalling vscode (removing .vscode folder; deleting the code folder under AppData/Roaming; deleting vscode)
- Uninstalling the extension.
- Multiple restarts.
- Removing all git credentials from credential manager.

I'm on Windows 11.

I was playing around with the black formatter around the time it stopped working.